# Export all subsites

Tags: powershell, stsadm, export

I am looking for a quick way to export all sub-sites from a web application and exclude the root url, is there a quick way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

maybe this can help :

```
Get-SPSite http://yourwabapp/sites/sitecol | Get-SPWeb | Where-Object  { $_.ParentWeb -Ne $null } | ForEach-Object { Export-SPWeb -Identity $_ -Path $_.ID }
```

you will need to adjust the export params according your needs

Comment: great thanks this works, is there a way to make it a single export or does it need to export each subsite individually?

Comment: I would need to import the sites as well as there are a lot, i would like to do it with a single import command

Comment: Just loop through the exported sites using PowerShell, and import each one. Something like dir $folderpath | For-Each {Import-SPWeb -Path $_.FullName -(Additional import parameters...)